# Numerical vs Symbolic Integration: Loss of precision

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, symbolic

I am trying to integrate the following expression over the time interval $0\leq t \leq \text{period}$.

```
(Cl - Cn)/Cl*(b Sin[2 Pi/peroid*t] f[t] - 2 (wl/peroid) Pi^2 b^2/wl^2)
```

where

```
f[t_] := ((Cl - Cn)^2/Cl 2 Pi^2 b^2/wl - Cn wl) b (wl/peroid) 
            Sin[2 Pi (wl/peroid)*t/wl]/((Cl - Cn)^2/Cl*b^2*
            wl*(Sin[2*Pi*(wl/peroid)*t/wl]^2) + (Cn - Cl) wl b^2/2*
            Cos[4 Pi (wl/peroid) t/wl] - Cl b^2 wl/2 - Cn wl^3/12)
```

$Cl, Cn, b, period, wl$ are all parameters and $t$ is the only variable.

I tried to perform the integration symbolically and *Mathematica* gave me the following result:

> ```
> -(((Cl - Cn) (2 b^2 (Cl - Cn) \[Pi]^2 + Cn wl^2))/((2 Cl^2 - 3 Cl Cn + Cn^2) wl))
> ```

To further verify that this symbolical expression is correct, I performed the above integration again but numerically with both *Mathematica* and *Matlab* with the following parameter values:

```
Cn = 0.001903418147340
Cl = 8.265172296997836/10000
b = 10/1000000
wl = 1000/1000000
peroid = 0.5
```

and I also evaluated the symbolic expression with the above set of values.
The numerical integration performed by *Mathematica* and *Matlab* agrees with each other.
However, both numerical integration performed by *Mathematica* and *Matlab* are 4 orders of magnitude different from the result obtained by evaluating the symbolic expression with the same set of parameter values. There's something going on, but I don't know what. Any suggestions ?

So far, I have checked that the function that I want to evaluate is smooth.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't do anything special and I get the same result for both methods.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

f[t_] := ((Cl - Cn)^2/Cl 2 Pi^2 b^2/wl - Cn wl) b (wl/peroid)
Sin[2 Pi (wl/peroid)*
    t/wl]/((Cl - Cn)^2/Cl*b^2*
     wl*(Sin[2*Pi*(wl/peroid)*t/wl]^2) + (Cn - Cl) wl b^2/2*
     Cos[4 Pi (wl/peroid) t/wl] - Cl b^2 wl/2 - Cn wl^3/12);

eq = (Cl - Cn)/
    Cl*(b Sin[2 Pi/peroid*t] f[t] - 2 (wl/peroid) Pi^2 b^2/wl^2);

Integrate[eq, {t, 0, peroid}]

% /. {b -> 10/1000000, Cn -> 0.001903418147340, 
  Cl -> 8.265172296997836/10000, wl -> 1000/1000000}

Block[{Cn = 0.001903418147340, Cl = 8.265172296997836/10000, 
  b = 10/1000000, wl = 1000/1000000, peroid = 0.5}, 
 NIntegrate[eq, {t, 0, peroid}]]

%% - %

(*
-((2 b^2 (Cl - Cn) π^2)/(Cl wl))
2.5719*10^-6
2.5719*10^-6
-2.96462*10^-21
*)
```